# Input content into a DIV within an HTML file from a PHP file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm not sure if this is even possible but if it is I imagine it would be via PHP (which I am a total beginner at).

Basically I have an .html file with an empty DIV tag in it and I am hoping to get the content of that DIV tag, which is stored in a .php file, and put it into the DIV.

To try and make this a bit clearer...

```
HTML FILE


<div id="content">

</div>
```

and...

```
CSS

#content {
position:relative;
width:700px;
max-height:550px;
min-height:10px;
overflow:auto;
}

#content h1 {
font-family:"Kristen ITC";
font-size:20px;
font-weight:bold;
margin-top:20px;
margin-bottom:0px;
margin-left:70px;
text-align:left;
color:#000000;
text-decoration:underline;
}

#content p {
font-family:"Bradley Hand ITC";
font-size:22px;
font-weight:bold;
margin-top:0px;
margin-bottom:0px;
margin-left:90px;
margin-right:130px;
text-align:left;
color:#000000;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

And then, I am hoping to have this...

```
<h1>- Chapter 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus molestie orci at orci blandit consectetur dapibus elit sollicitudin. Donec diam libero, feugiat vitae egestas eget, pellentesque eget tellus.</p>
    <h1>- Chapter 2</h1>
    <p>Phasellus in libero at ligula tincidunt convallis et a libero. Ut elementum molestie enim, vitae consequat mi imperdiet in. Ut metus justo, pharetra vel convallis et, eleifend vitae est. Aenean fringilla tincidunt nunc ac gravida.</p>
```

In a .php file, which I will then link to within the .html file, like this...

```
HTML FILE

<div id="content">

(Somehow link the .php. file here to get the <h1> and <p> stuff)

</div>
```

I hope this makes sense.

I have currently tried (remember I'm a beginner so don't laugh if I'm just being stupid)...

```
HTML FILE
<div id="content">

$contents = file_get_contents('current.php');

</div>
```

with the php file being...

```
PHP FILE

<?php
// print output
<h1>- Chapter 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus molestie orci at orci blandit consectetur dapibus elit sollicitudin. Donec diam libero, feugiat vitae egestas eget, pellentesque eget tellus.</p>
    <h1>- Chapter 2</h1>
    <p>Phasellus in libero at ligula tincidunt convallis et a libero. Ut elementum molestie enim, vitae consequat mi imperdiet in. Ut metus justo, pharetra vel convallis et, eleifend vitae est. Aenean fringilla tincidunt nunc ac gravida.</p>
?>
```

I have no idea what I'm doing, whether I'm relatively close to making this work, completely miles away from achieving it or if it's even possible.

In a perfect world where I could just use the .html file and .css file, it would look like this [example I made on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kp4Z9/2)

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're *including* a file (not 1:1 copy'ing the contents of the file). Try:

```
<div id="content">
<?php include('current.php'); ?>
</div>
```

This will strip `<?php ... ?>` tags, hope it helps. Documentation [is available](http://php.net/include).

Comment: Thanks hakre this worked! I had to remove the <?php..?> tags in my PHP file like Rob W suggested but it's all working now!

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
HTML FILE
<div id="content">
<?php
echo file_get_contents('current.php');
?>
</div>
```

Get rid of the `<?php` and `?>` in your "php" file, which just contains plain HTML.

If you want to add dynamic content, at the server's side, you have to contain PHP code within `<?php` and `?>`. When you're defining plain HTML, do NOT use `<?php`, because `<?php` tells the interpreter to parse the contents between `<?php` and `?>` as PHP code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, as you can probably tell I'm an extreme novice at this. I tried this method but it didn't want to work for me. However you have given me more understanding of the <?php...?> tags. I managed to use hakre's method along with your suggestion of deleting that tag and it's working great now. Thanks!

Comment: I suggested to use `file_get_contents` instead of `include`, because you made your `current.php` look like a HTML file. `include` actually parses PHP tags inside the included file, while `echo file_get_contents($file);` shows the file without parsing it.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the file_get_contents('sourcefile.php') function which allows retrieve the source file content.

If the source file includes code , you may use require() or include().
For further information read php.net manual.